# Browser sometimes does not request images from my Node server

Tags: browser, webserver, node.js

I have a Node server running. I log every request the server receives. When I type the url into my browser I am seeing some erratic behavior.

Sometimes all of the files are loaded and the page loads just fine. Other times only text files are requested (`.js`, `.css` etc) and the media files (`.jpeg`, `.png`) are never even requested from my server.

What would cause a browser to part of the time request the media files but part of the time ignore them?

Comment: Most browsers will cache images.

Comment: @heavyd ... But then so it will with css and js files...

Comment: I cleared the cache. No luck.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if c9.io (my IDE and debugging host) is not always forwarding all requests to my server.

Comment: I'm using latest version of chrome on a chromebook.

Comment: Same problem on iMac with safari.

Comment: In Chrome look in your Web Developer Tools (F12) under the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem, this is expected behavior. Modern browsers are very aggressive in how they cache images. And in the case of Chrome, it will retain web page content—images and external files—until the cache expires or is manually purged.

#### Content caching in Chrome.

To see this behavior in action, load your page in Chrome and follow your Node application’s logs. Now after the page loads, open up in the web inspector in Chrome—by doing a right click and hitting “Inspect”— and navigating to the “Network” tab. See screenshot below for reference. One of the options in the “Network” tab is labelled “Disable cache.”

If you check that box and then reload the page, the logs should now show all page elements being reloaded. This option in the inspector is a web developer’s tool for cases where cacheing gets in the way more than helps. FWIW, a similar option exists in Safari.

[image: The web inspector in Chrome and the “Network” tab with the “Disable cache” option checked.]

#### Web server cache control headers.

Another option is to see what headers your web server are sending by using the `curl -I` option from the command line. Simply get the URL an image—or element—from your web page, and view the headers via the `curl -I` option from the command line.

For example, let’s say you have an image named `test.png` on a server named `example.com` you could run this command to view the headers the web server sends when it processes a request for `test.png`:

```
curl -I http://example.com/test.png
```

Or—to see some real headers—let’s check the headers that are sent when accessing Google’s logo using this method:

```
curl -I curl -I https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

The returned headers I am seeing are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 13504
Date: Mon, 01 Jan 2018 02:59:24 GMT
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 2018 02:59:24 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=31536000
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 01:00:57 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
```

Note that `Cache-Control` header and it’s `max-age` value of 31536000. You know what that 31536000 translates to? That is a number in seconds and that is the equivalent of 1 year. So what Google’s servers are saying is the we browser should cache that image for 1 year before checking for a new one.

My guess is whatever Node application you are running must also have some kind of similar `Cache-Control` setting in place and if you want to see more frequent loads of content you should lower that `Cache-Control` setting. But typically this should only be done for development and testing purposes; for a production server leveraging the browser cache is a great thing. And getting the correct balance for application needs is a science within itself.